# Erro ao exibir valor de int

Tags: c, algoritmo

Ola, sou novo na linguagem C e gostaria de saber como arrumar este código.
Ao executar o código abaixo, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro na linha 22 e coluna 13:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Código:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void){


    int resul;

    int a;
    int b;

    printf("Digite o valor de A: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Digite o valor de B: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);


    resul = b;
    b = a;
    a = resul;

    printf(a);

    printf(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A função print exige que você informe uma string de formato. Do tipo: `printf("a: %d\n", a);`.

Comment: O que é esperado como saída?